# Why can't I create a temporary of this templated class with an lvalue constructor argument?

Tags: c++, templates, most-vexing-parse

For the life of me I can't seem to create a temporary of this class, why isn't it allowing me to?

```
template <typename T>
struct Dog
{
    Dog(T t) : tag(t) {}
    T tag; 
};

int main()
{
    int tag = 6;
    Dog<int>(6); // Works fine
    Dog<int>(tag); // On Visual Studio I get no default constructor exists for class Dog<int>
                  // On onlineGDB I get error: no matching function for call to ‘Dog::Dog()’
}
```

Also, what's the difference here, again between rvalue and lvalue:

```
Dog(6); // Deduces fine
Dog(tag); // Deduction fail, error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token
```

Also:

```
Dog<int>{tag}; // Works.
```

I take it because this is aggregate initialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dog(6);` and `Dog<int>(6);` declare temporary `Dog<int>`s, constructed with the value 6. Template argument deduction works fine in the first case, and the template parameter is explicit in the second.

However, `Dog(tag);` is *not* creating a temporary. It's a declarator of a variable `tag` of type `Dog<?>`. In general, the parentheses are redundant, i.e.
`int x`, `int (x)`, `int ((x))` are all equivalent. In this case, the error is that you haven't given an initializer with which to deduce the template parameter of `Dog`. The other error is you can't have parentheses around declarators where you're doing class template argument deduction.

`Dog<int>(tag);` is similar, it's a declarator of a variable `tag` of type `Dog<int>`. No deduction needs to be done since the parameter is explicit, but the error here is that you don't have a default constructor for `Dog`, and you haven't provided an argument for the constructor yourself.

`Dog{tag};` doesn't have the same issue as with parentheses. It declares a temporary `Dog` constructed with `tag` as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

Due to C++ parsing rules,

```
Dog<int>(tag);
```

is equivalent to

```
Dog<int> tag;
```

Brace initialization was introduced to avoid these parsing ambiguities:

```
Dog<int>{tag};
```